# UnityWebRequest Unity Cannot Connect

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

In Android:

> "Cannot connect to destination host"

I am using `UnityWebRequest` to request to my PC localhost, but I specifically put 192... in my URL since my server run on local, it is http does it has to do with insecure connection, what is the solution for this?

I tried several steps such as "Allow downloads over HTTP" still it is not working

Comment: 192 is a local network address and cannot be accessed by anything else except things on your network

Comment: Yes and my phone/android is connected to that same network

Comment: Can you browse to the address from the android device?

Comment: Yes, responds perfectly they it supposed to

Comment: then much as Im not an android maker of things, id say you havent told android you need that and so it doesnt allow it